# Values of background shorthand property wrongly expanded when trying to call HTMLElement.style

Tags: javascript, css, shorthand

In styles for an element I have a few inline CSS declarations including a shorthand declaration for background

```
<style>
  :root{
    --bg-white: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  }
</style>

<div style="background: var(--bg-white); ... "></div>
```

but when iterating over HTMLElement.style the shorthand property looks like it's wrongly expanded

```
 for (const declaration of Array.from(target.style)) { 
   const value = target.style.getPropertyValue(declaration)

   console.log(`${declaration}: ${value}`)
 }
```

This should print out `background-color: var(--bg-white)` per [HTMLElement.style documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style), but I get `background-color: ''`

> Shorthand properties are expanded. If you set style="border-top: 1px solid black", the longhand properties (border-top-color, border-top-style, and border-top-width) are set instead.

Has anyone encountered this before?

Comment: it should not print `var(--bg-white)` but the computed value of the variable if it contain a valid value for background

Comment: Do you use bootstrap or did you specify the CSS variable yourself anywhere? If `--bg-white` was not specified anywhere, it while evaluate to an empty string.

Comment: @TemaniAfif HTMLElement.style should not print out the computed value, that's what getComputedStyle() does. Just double checked in the console.

Comment: @L483 I meant to ask this as a general and not a direct question, so I just omitted that part of the code. I added it though to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This should print out background-color: var(--bg-white) per HTMLElement.style documentation on MDN, but I get background-color: ''

If you use `HTMLElement.style`, it will return what is directly applied (not computed) through the `style`attribute.

In that case the browser can't know what the `var(...)` in `background: var(--bg-white);` will resolve and to which `background-...` properties it will contain (The contents of the variable will be placed where the `var(...)` statement is and then the resulting value will be parsed.

So if you e.g. have `--bg-white: content-box radial-gradient(crimson, skyblue);`  then your `--bg-white` will actually influence multiple properties.

Comment: upvoted, thereby i was able to point exactly where the OP's code failed

Answer (score 1):

The problem that you use `Array.from(target.style)` to get a default iterator for `target.style`. It doesn't include the background property. According to the spec a shorthand property is expanded to its parts.

Everything is explained in the code.

Thanks to @t.niese for a tip in the comments.

```html
<div id="test" style="background: var(--bg-white);">Test</div>

<script>

 const target = document.querySelector('#test');
 
 // style is itarable
 console.log(target.style[Symbol.iterator]);
 
 // but doesn't include background in the iterator
 console.log(...target.style);
 
 // but background is iterable!
 console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target.style, 'background'));
 
 // we can see it in Object.keys
 console.log(Object.keys(target.style).filter(name => name === 'background'));
 
 // so we can iterate it anyway
 for(const k in target.style){
    if(k === 'background'){
      console.log(target.style[k]);
    }
 }
 
   // Object.entries works too
 console.log(Object.entries(target.style).filter(([name]) => name === 'background'));
 
 // or access directly
 console.log(target.style.getPropertyValue('background'));
 console.log(target.style.background);
 
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The real problem is that I don't need the element's computed value, rather it's CSS definition -- so in this case I need the value to be var(--bg-white).

Comment: What is the reason for you parsing the attribute? For both `target.style.background` and `rules.background`  I get the exact same output. And  `background-color`  would be `''` also for your code if `background: var(--bg-white);` is the style.

Comment: @okejminja update the answer with a proper one. the previous ones were bullshit...